# What is the impact of calling io_service::run method twice

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio

The following schema come from boost asio documentation:

[image]

I understand that if I call `io_service::run` method twice (in two separate threads), I will have two threads to deque events from the completion Event Queue via Asynchronous Event Demultiplexer am I right?

More precisely, my doubt is on the parrallelization achieve by multiple call of `io_service::run` method. For instance when dealing with socket, if for example I have two sockets bound on the same `io_service object`, each socket calling `socket.async_read_some` method, does it involved the 2 registered callbacks (via async_read_some method) can be called concurently when calling  `io_service::run` twice.

Comment: You understand it correctly. Here is useful link which explains it in details:
http://theboostcpplibraries.com/boost.asio-scalability

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your assumptions are correct. Each thread which calls `io_service::run()` will dequeue and execute handlers (simple function objects) in parallel. This of course only makes sense if you have more than one source of events feeding the io_service (such as two sockets, a socket and a timer, several simultaneous `post()` calls and so on).

Each call to a socket's `async_read()` will result in exactly one handler being queued in the io_service. Only one of your threads will dequeue it and execute it.

Be careful not to call async_read() more than once at a time *per socket*.